# Unexpected end of stream on okhttp3

Tags: retrofit2, okhttp

I had followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35238894/android-retrofit-2-authenticator-result) to refresh access token. While adding Authenticator to okHttp  getting error of **Unexpected end of stream on okhttp3** from retrofit call back **onFailure** method

```
public class TokenAuthenticator implements Authenticator {
    AccessTokenRefreshModel accessTokenRefreshModel = null;

    @Override
    public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {
        Call<UserLogin> call = iService.refreshAccessToken(BuildConfig.CLIENT_ID, refreshToken);
        UserLogin userLogin = call.execute().body();
        // Add new header to rejected request and retry it
        return response.request().newBuilder()
                .header(AUTHORIZATION, userLogin.getAccessToken())
                .build();
    }
}


Call<User> call = iService.createuser(user);
call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
  @Override
  public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
    //**Unexpected end of stream on okhttp3** 
  }
```

Comment: Are you using logging interceptor?

Comment: @Debanjan yes i am using logging interceptor.

Comment: Remove the logging interceptor and check once.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
UserLogin userLogin = call.execute().body();
```

try

```
retrofit2.Response<UserLogin> tokenResponse = call.execute();
```