# How do I call REST API with bearer token from an Android app?

Tags: java, android, api, rest, bearer-token

I'm new in Android and programming as well. I would like to build an Android app with user login and registration. What's the easiest way to make REST API calls on Android for a beginner?
I also have to pass a bearer token in the header and two parameter in body (name and password).

Comment: I have been working over this in past years. I can suggest you the way to do it, I am not having code at the moment

Comment: Send a post request using apache HTTP client and get the token from the response and concat Bearer and a space on start of the token Put this token in the header of the 2nd post request and send the post request to your API and get the required response back

Comment: hope that helps

Comment: concat bearer token like this: Bearer your_token_string

Comment: please also add the response header..

Comment: Hi,
I see you use Postman , you can [generate code snippets in postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/#generating-code-snippets-in-postman)

Comment: If you are using HttpRequest please add header to your request. There will be a method or a property to add  header to your  request . for example `requestObject.Add("Authorization","Bearer Token"+your token)` ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)

> Retrofit is a REST Client for Java and Android. It makes it relatively
> easy to retrieve and upload JSON (or other structured data) via a REST
> based webservice. <sup>[source](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html)</sup>

also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41082979/10491674)