# Okhttp refresh expired token when multiple requests are sent to the server

Tags: java, android, http, retrofit, okhttp

I have a `ViewPager` and three webservice calls are made when `ViewPager` is loaded simultaneously.

When first one returns 401, `Authenticator` is called and I refresh the token inside `Authenticator`, but remaining 2 requests are already sent to the server with old refresh token and fails with 498 which is captured in Interceptor and app is logged out.

This is not the ideal behaviour I would expect. I would like to keep the 2nd and 3rd request in the queue and when the token is refreshed, retry the queued request.

Currently, I have a variable to indicate if token refresh is ongoing in `Authenticator`, in that case, I cancel all subsequent request in the `Interceptor` and user has to manually refresh the page or I can logout the user and force user to login.

What is a good solution or architecture for the above problem using okhttp 3.x for Android?

EDIT: The problem I want to solve is in general and I would not like to sequence my calls. i.e. wait for one call to finish and refresh the token and then only send rest of the request on the activity and fragment level.

Code was requested. This is a standard code for `Authenticator`:

```
public class CustomAuthenticator implements Authenticator {

    @Inject AccountManager accountManager;
    @Inject @AccountType String accountType;
    @Inject @AuthTokenType String authTokenType;

    @Inject
    public ApiAuthenticator(@ForApplication Context context) {
    }

    @Override
    public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {

        // Invaidate authToken
        String accessToken = accountManager.peekAuthToken(account, authTokenType);
        if (accessToken != null) {
            accountManager.invalidateAuthToken(accountType, accessToken);
        }
        try {
                // Get new refresh token. This invokes custom AccountAuthenticator which makes a call to get new refresh token.
                accessToken = accountManager.blockingGetAuthToken(account, authTokenType, false);
                if (accessToken != null) {
                    Request.Builder requestBuilder = response.request().newBuilder();

                    // Add headers with new refreshToken

                    return requestBuilder.build();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                Timber.e(t, t.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Some questions similar to this:
[OkHttp and Retrofit, refresh token with concurrent requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44386722/okhttp-and-retrofit-refresh-token-with-concurrent-requests?rq=1)

Comment: please post some code

Comment: can you post your authenticator code? thanks. also why you get 498 from your api with your expired token?

Comment: @savepopulation 498 means Invalid Token. 2 requests that were sent along with 1st request have old token and request fails with 498 error code.

Comment: so what is blocking you of repeating the 2nd and 3rd request when you get the refreshed token?

Comment: @matrix I have to queue the failed request in Interceptor and retry it with new refresh token. First, I have to have an event to notice new refresh token is available then I have to retry all failed request. I havenot found a way to do it in the Interceptor. Also, it doesnot seem like a good solution and I am wondering whats the common pattern to refresh the token using okhttp

Comment: oh got it. i'll write down my answer when i have time but simply you can create a thread which refreshes token and do your syncronised retrofit call in your thread. you can define a CountDownLatch and if your refresh thread is working wait countdown if it's not start refresh thread. finally when you refreshed token save it and countDown your lacth and let the other requests read refreshed token and proceed request.

Comment: a response using RxJava is acceptable?

Comment: When you get the 498 error in the interceptor, can you callback your caller with "onError()", and it will do a retry? (It will have a valid token this time)

Comment: I've asked this because I think this is the correct way to do it: parallel gets, and retries at the caller level, not the retrofit level

Comment: @sat I have the same problem, did you come to a solution?

Comment: Through synchronized code blocks you can resolve the problem.
https://medium.com/bazaar-tech/the-dark-side-of-overusing-concurrency-7b9fa0dab9ab

Comment: check out my solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77206302/11671900

Answer (score 17):

You can do this:

Add those as data members:

```
// these two static variables serve for the pattern to refresh a token
private final static ConditionVariable LOCK = new ConditionVariable(true);
private static final AtomicBoolean mIsRefreshing = new AtomicBoolean(false);
```

and then on the intercept method:

```
@Override
    public Response intercept(@NonNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();

        // 1. sign this request
        ....

        // 2. proceed with the request
        Response response = chain.proceed(request);

        // 3. check the response: have we got a 401?
        if (response.code() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED) {

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(token)) {
                /*
                *  Because we send out multiple HTTP requests in parallel, they might all list a 401 at the same time.
                *  Only one of them should refresh the token, because otherwise we'd refresh the same token multiple times
                *  and that is bad. Therefore we have these two static objects, a ConditionVariable and a boolean. The
                *  first thread that gets here closes the ConditionVariable and changes the boolean flag.
                */
                if (mIsRefreshing.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
                    LOCK.close();

                    /* we're the first here. let's refresh this token.
                    *  it looks like our token isn't valid anymore.
                    *  REFRESH the actual token here
                    */

                    LOCK.open();
                    mIsRefreshing.set(false);
                } else {
                    // Another thread is refreshing the token for us, let's wait for it.
                    boolean conditionOpened = LOCK.block(REFRESH_WAIT_TIMEOUT);

                    // If the next check is false, it means that the timeout expired, that is - the refresh
                    // stuff has failed.
                    if (conditionOpened) {

                        // another thread has refreshed this for us! thanks!
                        // sign the request with the new token and proceed
                        // return the outcome of the newly signed request
                        response = chain.proceed(newRequest);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // check if still unauthorized (i.e. refresh failed)
        if (response.code() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED) {
            ... // clean your access token and prompt for request again.
        }

        // returning the response to the original request
        return response;
    }
```

In this way you will only send 1 request to refresh the token and then for every other you will have the refreshed token.

Comment: you are not using `Authenticator` interface

Comment: and what if request was canceled and it could reach `mIsRefreshing.set(false);`? in this case would not be able to reset it

Comment: and you can just compare accessToken like this in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62950438/using-coroutine-runblock-with-the-authenticator-to-handle-401-response-from-retr

Answer (score 17):

It is important to note, that `accountManager.blockingGetAuthToken` (or the non-blocking version) could still be called somewhere else, other than the interceptor. Hence the correct place to prevent this issue from happening would be *within* the authenticator.

We want to make sure that the first thread that needs an access token will retrieve it, and possible other threads should just register for a callback to be invoked when the first thread finished retrieving the token.
The good news is, that `AbstractAccountAuthenticator` already has a way of delivering asynchronous results, namely `AccountAuthenticatorResponse`, on which you can call `onResult` or `onError`.

---

The following sample consists of 3 blocks.

The **first** one is about making sure that only one thread fetches the access token while other threads just register their `response` for a callback.

The **second** part is just a dummy empty result bundle. Here, you would load your token, possibly refresh it, etc.

The **third** part is what you do once you have your result (or error). You have to make sure to call the response for every other thread that might have registered.

```
boolean fetchingToken;
List<AccountAuthenticatorResponse> queue = null;

@Override
public Bundle getAuthToken(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account, String authTokenType, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {

  synchronized (this) {
    if (fetchingToken) {
      // another thread is already working on it, register for callback
      List<AccountAuthenticatorResponse> q = queue;
      if (q == null) {
        q = new ArrayList<>();
        queue = q;
      }
      q.add(response);
      // we return null, the result will be sent with the `response`
      return null;
    }
    // we have to fetch the token, and return the result other threads
    fetchingToken = true;
  }

  // load access token, refresh with refresh token, whatever
  // ... todo ...
  Bundle result = Bundle.EMPTY;

  // loop to make sure we don't drop any responses
  for ( ; ; ) {
    List<AccountAuthenticatorResponse> q;
    synchronized (this) {
      // get list with responses waiting for result
      q = queue;
      if (q == null) {
        fetchingToken = false;
        // we're done, nobody is waiting for a response, return
        return null;
      }
      queue = null;
    }

    // inform other threads about the result
    for (AccountAuthenticatorResponse r : q) {
      r.onResult(result); // return result
    }

    // repeat for the case another thread registered for callback
    // while we were busy calling others
  }
}
```

Just make sure to return `null` on all paths when using the `response`.

You could obviously use other means to synchronize those code blocks, like atomics as shown by @matrix in another response. I made use of `synchronized`, because I believe this to be the easiest to grasp implementation, since this is a great question and everyone should be doing this ;)

---

The above sample is an adapted version of an [emitter loop described here](http://akarnokd.blogspot.co.at/2015/05/operator-concurrency-primitives.html), where it goes into great detail about concurrency. This blog is a great source if you're interested in how RxJava works under the hood.

Comment: Playing around with this and am seeing that fetchingToken is never true. Each call to `getAuthToken` just runs through the whole method. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Jack Unless you made an error implementing it this just means that you didn't encounter any racing conditions. This code makes sure that IFF multiple threads need a new accessToken only one requests it and passes the results to the others. I was able to test this by invalidating the accessToken before firing 10+ API calls at once on background threads. Then one thread will do the lookup, while the others wait for the result.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. That's what I assumed. I'm calling `getAuthToken()` from within an okhttp `Authenticator`. I'm using RxJava and throwing all the original requests on the `io` thread which just ends up calling `getAuthToken` apparently not in a way I'd expect for synchronization in the method. I'm fairly new to synchronization so I'm still working through it. If the synchronized method is being called from the same thread would it still wait?

Comment: @Jack How are you observing your code? If you use the debugger you might pause all the threads leading to the sequential behavior you see. How do you refresh your token? Is the call returning the accessToken from cache, or are you doing a network call? If you just lookup a cached token it will be too quick, so you would actually need an IO call to the server to make full use of the code. I can't really help you remotely to debug your code, but I recommend that you use `Log` and make sure that you are actually using IO to refresh the access token (which switches threads and takes longer)

Comment: Ah yes, I had that thought in the back of mind that if I'm setting a break point I'm basically making it synchronous. I'll play around with it some more. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @DavidMedenjakis there any full code sample for that please?

Answer (score 5):

You can try with this application level interceptor

```
 private class HttpInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();

        //Build new request
        Request.Builder builder = request.newBuilder();
        builder.header("Accept", "application/json"); //if necessary, say to consume JSON

        String token = settings.getAccessToken(); //save token of this request for future
        setAuthHeader(builder, token); //write current token to request

        request = builder.build(); //overwrite old request
        Response response = chain.proceed(request); //perform request, here original request will be executed

        if (response.code() == 401) { //if unauthorized
            synchronized (httpClient) { //perform all 401 in sync blocks, to avoid multiply token updates
                String currentToken = settings.getAccessToken(); //get currently stored token

                if(currentToken != null && currentToken.equals(token)) { //compare current token with token that was stored before, if it was not updated - do update

                    int code = refreshToken() / 100; //refresh token
                    if(code != 2) { //if refresh token failed for some reason
                        if(code == 4) //only if response is 400, 500 might mean that token was not updated
                            logout(); //go to login screen
                        return response; //if token refresh failed - show error to user
                    }
                }

                if(settings.getAccessToken() != null) { //retry requires new auth token,
                    setAuthHeader(builder, settings.getAccessToken()); //set auth token to updated
                    request = builder.build();
                    return chain.proceed(request); //repeat request with new token
                }
            }
        }

        return response;
    }

    private void setAuthHeader(Request.Builder builder, String token) {
        if (token != null) //Add Auth token to each request if authorized
            builder.header("Authorization", String.format("Bearer %s", token));
    }

    private int refreshToken() {
        //Refresh token, synchronously, save it, and return result code
        //you might use retrofit here
    }

    private int logout() {
        //logout your user
    }
}
```

You can set interceptor like this to okHttp instance

```
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

    OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    httpClient.interceptors().add(new HttpInterceptor());

    final RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(BuildConfig.REST_SERVICE_URL)
            .setClient(new OkClient(httpClient))
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.BASIC)
            .build();

    remoteService = restAdapter.create(RemoteService.class);
```

Hope this helps!!!!

Comment: you are not using `Authenticator` interface

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with authenticator, the id is the number of the request, only for identification. Comments are in Spanish

```
 private final static Lock locks = new ReentrantLock();

httpClient.authenticator(new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            public Request authenticate(@NonNull Route route,@NonNull Response response) throws IOException {

                Log.e("Error" , "Se encontro un 401 no autorizado y soy el numero : " + id);

                //Obteniendo token de DB
                SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences(
                        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                String token_db = prefs.getString("refresh_token","");

                //Comparando tokens
                if(mToken.getRefreshToken().equals(token_db)){

                    locks.lock(); 

                    try{
                        //Obteniendo token de DB
                         prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences(
                                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                        String token_db2 = prefs.getString("refresh_token","");
                        //Comparando tokens
                        if(mToken.getRefreshToken().equals(token_db2)){

                            //Refresh token
                            APIClient tokenClient = createService(APIClient.class);
                            Call<AccessToken> call = tokenClient.getRefreshAccessToken(API_OAUTH_CLIENTID,API_OAUTH_CLIENTSECRET, "refresh_token", mToken.getRefreshToken());
                            retrofit2.Response<AccessToken> res = call.execute();
                            AccessToken newToken = res.body();
                            // do we have an access token to refresh?
                            if(newToken!=null && res.isSuccessful()){
                                String refreshToken = newToken.getRefreshToken();

                                    Log.e("Entra", "Token actualizado y soy el numero :  " + id + " : " + refreshToken);

                                    prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                    prefs.edit().putBoolean("log_in", true).apply();
                                    prefs.edit().putString("access_token", newToken.getAccessToken()).apply();
                                    prefs.edit().putString("refresh_token", refreshToken).apply();
                                    prefs.edit().putString("token_type", newToken.getTokenType()).apply();

                                    locks.unlock();

                                    return response.request().newBuilder()
                                            .header("Authorization", newToken.getTokenType() + " " + newToken.getAccessToken())
                                            .build();

                             }else{
                                //Dirigir a login
                                Log.e("redirigir", "DIRIGIENDO LOGOUT");

                                locks.unlock();
                                return null;
                            }

                        }else{
                            //Ya se actualizo tokens

                            Log.e("Entra", "El token se actualizo anteriormente, y soy el no : " + id );

                            prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                            String type = prefs.getString("token_type","");
                            String access = prefs.getString("access_token","");

                            locks.unlock();

                            return response.request().newBuilder()
                                    .header("Authorization", type + " " + access)
                                    .build();
                        }

                    }catch (Exception e){
                        locks.unlock();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return null;
                    }


                }
                return null;
            }
        });
```