# Rxjava - How to retry call after doOnError completes

Tags: android, rx-java, onerror, retrywhen

I`m struggling to retry my rxjava Single call **after** another network call is done in doOnError:

```
restApi.getStuff()
       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
       .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
       .doOnError {
            getRefreshToken(it, AuthenticationManager.Callback{
                retry(1)
            })
       }
       .subscribeBy(
             onSuccess = { response ->},
             onError = { throwable ->}
       )
```

But the retry method cannot be invoked inside the doOnError method.
Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Are you facing an issue when your session key / User token expires?

Comment: yes, thats why i need to refresh the token when it expires

Comment: Check this, you dont need to do a fresh call in onError: https://blog.jayway.com/2016/12/07/retrofit-auto-relogin-401-response/ -- This is incase you are using retrofit.

Comment: we get the callback to doOnError after it is disposed.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I used a different approach with creating an Interceptor for token authorization (@Skynet suggestion led me to it).
Here is more info about it: 
[Refreshing OAuth token using Retrofit without modifying all calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22450036/refreshing-oauth-token-using-retrofit-without-modifying-all-calls/28285627)

Answer (score -1):

if you want to check the response and then retry you should try this:

```
  restApi.getStuff()
       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
       .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
       .retryWhen(errors -> errors.flatMap(error -> {
          // for some exceptions
          if (error instanceof IOException) {
               return Observable.just(null);
          }

         // otherwise
         return Observable.error(error);
         })
         )
```

otherwise

```
restApi.getStuff()
       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
       .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
       .retry()
```

from the docs, retry() responds to onError. [link](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/retry.html)

Comment: I solved my problem already in another way, but your solutions gives me: 'Unnresolved reference: errors'

Comment: This is incomplete. The question is not how to retry upon error, but how to chain an authentication token renew and then retry upon success. Or more generally, how to chain a call before actually retrying.